# Animating Frames

Tags: frame, bufferedimage

Which Class should I use to animate a set of frames?I did like this.It worked well.That is I could animate picture.Which class is the best?

```
public JLabel frame;
public Image[] frames;

public Bird() {
    frames = new Image[5];
    frames[0] = getToolkit().getImage("Resources\\bird_swing_up2.png");
    frames[1] = getToolkit().getImage("Resources\\bird_swing_up.png");
    frames[2] = getToolkit().getImage("Resources\\bird_swing_down.png");
    frames[3] = getToolkit().getImage("Resources\\bird_swing_up.png");
    frames[4] = getToolkit().getImage("Resources\\bird_swing_up2.png");

}
```

I animate this in another class like this?Is it ok?is this method better way to do?

```
private Image city;
private Image ground;
private int x = 0;
private Timer speedController;

private Bird bird;
private Timer timer;
int i = 0;


public Board() {
    super();
    ground = getToolkit().getImage("Resources\\ground.png");
    city = getToolkit().getImage("Resources\\city.png");
    speedController = new Timer(5, new GroundSpeed());
    speedController.start();

    bird = new Bird();
    timer = new Timer(50, new Fly());
    timer.start();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(city, 0, 0, 1082, 450, this);
    g.drawImage(ground, x, 372, this);
    g.drawImage(ground, x + 350, 372, this);
    g.drawImage(bird.frames[i], 100, 100, this);


    if(x == -350){
        x = 0;
    }
}

public class GroundSpeed implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        x--;
        repaint();
    }

}


public class Fly implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //frame = new JLabel(frames[i]);
        i++;
        if(i == 4){
            i = 0;
        }
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any better way of animating Images.I am using to Timer objects in class.First for animating bird.Second for animating ground.But my ground moves slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. unfortunately, **there is no magical Class in Java** to do that, meaning you will have to write your own animation mechanism.

There are 2 main techniques for creating animations:

- Frame-based animation
- Time-based animation

Timee-based animation is always preferable! One of the best stuff there is about this subject is [available here](http://blog.sklambert.com/using-time-based-animation-implement/). It shares *jsFiddle* examples demonstrating every technique explained in the post.

Not too long ago [I translated that code to C++/Qt](https://goo.gl/FdDLAE):

[image]